# how to create international country language specific url

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter

I want to Create url like this

http://www.example.com/uk-en/category/subcategory/etc..
http://www.example.com/in-en/category/subcategory/etc..

When the user access our site from india Url look like this
http://www.example.com/in-en
When the user access our site from other country Url look like this
http://www.example.com/country_code-country_language
how can i do this using codeigniter or web services

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/codeigniter-2.1-internationalization-i18n

Answer (score 0):

In your default controller or in a hook (pre_controller), you need to have this

```
$_language =substr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"],0,2); 
redirect($_language, 'refresh');
```

You can add another validation like ip address to know if is a english from usa, uk, etc, but if some english speaker travel to another country, the validation will be fail.